# Почему мапить view модели на доменные объекты через автомаппер - это плохая идея (или а как вы мапите view модели на домены)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, automapper

Уважаемые коллеги! Может кто то внятно русским языком объяснить, почему мапить view модели на доменные объекты через автомаппер - это плохая идея?

Расскажу, с чего появился этот вопрос. Некоторое время назад мои методы в контроллерах выгладили примерно так (просьба не утруждать себя внимательным чтением этого метода, просто отметьте для себя, сколько тут ручного маппинга):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] FunnelViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var advertisers = await _advertiserRepository.Advertisers
            .Where(x => viewModel.Advertisers.Select(y => y.AdvertiserId).Contains(x.AdvertiserId)).ToListAsync();

        var category = await _categoryRepository.Categories
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => viewModel.Category.CategoryId == x.CategoryId);

        if (!advertisers.Any())
        {
            ModelState.TryAddModelError("Advertisers", "Нет ни одного рекла");
        }

        if (category == null)
        {
            ModelState.TryAddModelError("Category", "Необходимо выбрать категорию");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var advertisersFunnels = new List<AdvertiserFunnel>();

        var funnel = new Funnel();
        funnel.Category = category;
        funnel.IsActive = viewModel.IsActive;
        funnel.IsChoiceAllApps = viewModel.IsChoiceAllApps;
        funnel.Title = viewModel.Title;
        funnel.PackageIds = viewModel.Applications.Select(x => x.AppId).ToList();
        funnel.FunnelId = viewModel.FunnelId;

        foreach (var advertiser in advertisers)
        {
            advertisersFunnels.Add(new AdvertiserFunnel
            {
                Funnel = funnel,
                Advertiser = advertiser,
            });
        }

        funnel.AdvertiserFunnels = advertisersFunnels;

        List<CustomerTypeFunnel> customerTypeFunnels = new List<CustomerTypeFunnel>();

        foreach (var type in viewModel.CustomerTypes)
        {
            var currentItem = new CustomerTypeFunnel()
            {
                CustomerTypeId = type,
                Funnel = funnel
            };

            customerTypeFunnels.Add(currentItem);
        }

        funnel.CustomerTypeFunnels = customerTypeFunnels;

        await _funnelRepository.SaveAsync(funnel);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

А суть одна. Просто найти нужные модели в базе, установить связи и сохранить. Это расстраивало меня. Контроллеры были загромождены подобным кодом и громоздки.

Я часто слышал про автомаппер. Решил попробовать. Работает элементарно. 
Инжектим через DI. Я работаю с .NET Core и у меня это выглядит так:

В классе `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

Далее надо создать так называемый профйл, где мы объясняем мапперу, что на что маппить. Вот в моем случае его типовой вид (без подробностей маппинга он просто сопоставит поля с одинаковыми именами и типами):

```
public class ApplicationProfile : Profile
{
    public ApplicationProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ApplicationViewModel, Application>();
    }
}
```

Далее в контроллере остается только написать:

```
var application = _mapper.Map<ApplicationViewModel, Application>(viewModel);

await _applicationRepository.AddAsync(application);
```

Это в методе Create например. Удобно. Но что если у нас такой доменный объект:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId {get; set;} 
    public bool Again {get; set;}
    public Customer Customer {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateTimeFromPhone {get; set;}
    public string EventType {get; set;}
    public JObject Data { get; set; }
}
```

И вот такая view model

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "type can not be empty")]
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    [DisplayName("type")]
    public string EventType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "date can not be empty")]
    [JsonProperty("date")]
    [DisplayName("date")]
    public int DateTimeFromPhone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public JObject Data { get; set; }
}
```

Видите, тут поле Again? Логика такая. В систему идут через Rest Api некоторые события от пользователей. Это типа аналитика. То есть, перед записью надо бы проверить, было ли у пользователя событие с таким типом. Есть - ставим Again в true. Вы скажете, ну и проверь в контроллере. Но у меня сигнатура метода в контроллере выглядит так:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Events([FromBody] List<EventViewModel> viewModel, Customer customer)
```

`List<EventViewModel> viewModel` - говорит о том, что я приму json такого вида:

```
[
{// объект},
{// объект},
{// объект},
...
]
```

То есть много событий за раз. Можно конечно написать цикл. Но это опять появление в контроллере непонятной бизнес-логики, покуда обязанность контроллера просто реагировать на действия пользователя. А не какие-то циклы выполнять. Можно написать сервис, который возьмет этот лист view моделей и уже прокрутит их, установит, где повторные события (поле Again) и сохранит. Но смотрите, как я нашел, как это сделать через автомаппер. Я пишу так называемый резолвер и кое-какие правила маппинга.

Резолвер.

```
public class CustomerEventResolver : IValueResolver<EventViewModel, CustomerEvent, bool>
{
    private readonly ICustomerEventRepository _eventRepository;

    public CustomerEventResolver(ICustomerEventRepository eventRepository)
    {
        _eventRepository = eventRepository;
    }

    // TODO сделать этот метод асинхронным
    public bool Resolve(EventViewModel source, CustomerEvent destination, bool member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var customer = (Customer) context.Options.Items["Customer"];

        bool again = _eventRepository.IsExist(x =>
            x.Customer == customer && x.EventType == source.EventType);

        return again;
    }
}
```

Обновленный профайл:

```
    public EventProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<EventViewModel, CustomerEvent>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DateTimeFromPhone,
                opt
                    => opt.MapFrom(src
                        => Common.Int2DateTime(src.DateTimeFromPhone)))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Customer,
            opt
                => opt.MapFrom(
                    (src, dest, destMember, context)
                        => (Customer) context.Items["Customer"]))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Again,
            opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomerEventResolver>());
    }
```

Смотрите как здорово! После вызова всего этого добра у меня готовый список новых доменных объектов со всеми полями (еще и объект Customer туда докинул)! Остается только вставить в репозиторий и сохранить! Вот кстати [ссылка на документацию](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper) по этим резолверам.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Events([FromBody] List<EventViewModel> viewModel, Customer customer)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // мапим view модель к моделе и ставим кастомера.
        var customerEvents =
            _mapper.Map<List<EventViewModel>, List<CustomerEvent>>(viewModel,
                options => options.Items["Customer"] = customer);

        await _customerEventRepository.AddRangeAsync(customerEvents);
        await _customerEventRepository.SaveAsync();          

        return Ok(new {status = "ok", description = "Done"});
    }
```

Только вот досада, этот метод `Resolve` в резолвере не имеет асинхронной версии. Значит, мне не получится в нем вызвать асинхронные методы моего репозитория. Я стал копать и нашел вот такую [статью](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/)

Хотя статья достаточно старая, и я не уверен, что эти резолверы были в 2013 (я не проверял), она говорит о том, что в таком ключе использовать автомаппер - это антипаттерн. 
На гитхабе есть также [обсуждения](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1226) на эту тему. Автор утверждает, что асинхронного резолвера не будет. И я совершенно не могу понять почему нет возможности или альтернативы автомаппера для такого сценария как я описал. На мой взгляд это было бы мега-удобно. Прошу обратить особое внимание на [этот пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57575385/automapper-custom-value-resolvers-async) (на комментарии особенно). Пост свежий, 2019 год, судя по всему так и не решился автор автомаппера сделать свой автомаппер для такого сценария использования.

Вопрос, может все таки как то можно использовать автомаппер в таком сценарии?Да понятно, что в моем конкретном примере с `Again` это не сработает. Но что по поводу других случаев? Что, например, если я буду мапить только примитивные типы, и не буду в резолверах использовать блокирующие методы (тем более вызовы,связанные с EF). Что если моя view модель будет, например такой:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Application ID is required.")]
    [JsonProperty("app_id")]
    public string AppId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Advertiser ID is required.")]
    [JsonProperty("advertiser_id")]
    public int AdvertiserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Platform code is required.")]
    [JsonProperty("platform_code")]
    public string Platform { get; set; }
}
```

А доменная модель такой:

```
Application  
{
    public int ApplicationId {get; set;}
    public string AppId {get; set;}
    public int AdvertiserId {get; set;}
    public Advertiser Advertiser {get; set;}
 }
```

То есть я буду мапить только примитивные типы, не трогая, например, навигационное свойство `Advertiser` а лишь устанавливая `AdvertiserId`. Хотя бы в таком ключе его можно использовать (я имею ввиду сценарий DTO to Model)?

А как вы мапите свои вью модели на доменные объекты? Поделитесь пожалуйста практическим опытом. Спасибо, что уделили внимание. Буду очень благодарен за любые свединия по данному вопросу.

P.S. Особую боль доставляет мапить руками многие-ко-многим в EF Core!

Comment: Почему вы решили, что циклу в контроллере не место, но при этом думаете, что лазать в базу при маппинге - это нормально? Маппинг, по идее, это отображение а на б. Если вам надо тут лазать в бд или что еще - это уже не маппинг, это уже фабрика.

Comment: @tym32167 мне показалось это очень удобным. А что вы скажете по поводу того, чтоб на лазить в маппере в базу, а мапить только примитивные типы в сценарии view model -> domain object? Не используя при этом навигационные свойства, а используя лишь Id. Я имею ввиду, что если у меня есть навигационное свойство `Advertiser`, то я бы докинул еще int AdvertiserId (при том, что такое было бы во view моделе), смаппил бы и вставил бы в базу. Или вообще использовать маппер в таком сценарии недопустимо?

Comment: @tym32167 а как вы обычно мапите, можете поделиться способом? Используете ли вы автомаппер в таком сценарии, как view model -> domain object?

Comment: @tym32167 где вы храните ваши фабрики для маппинга? У меня проект Api и Web. Домены одни на всех, view модели разные. В каждом проекте по папке с фабриками? Это нормально будет?

Comment: Мапить примитивные типы - это нормальная практика. Менять типы для доступа к данным только для маппинга я бы не советовал. В моем случае, я делаю маппинг на доменный объект и что получится засылаю в репозиторий, а в репозитории наклепал нужные мне методы - но это у меня так, в моем небольшом проекте. Для маппинга использую автомаппер, настройки маппинга вынес в отдельный метод внутри startup класса, хотя по хорошему надо бы в отдельный класс их вынести.

Comment: @tym32167 то есть, я так понял, вы все же используете автомаппер, как я описал в самом низу своего вопроса? То есть view модель на доменный объект, но без использования навигационных свойств (чтоб в базу не ходить)? Или я что то не так понял? При таком сценарии, надо быть уверенным, что тот ид, который я маплю соответствует реальной сущности в бд. Я для этого фильтров наделал. `[AdvertiserExistsInDb]` - как то так. Это нормально? В результате, если кто-то из дев тулов в браузере поменяет данные на фронте у меня сервер не выдаст Foreign key exception. Нормально? Или фильтры не для этого?

Comment: Да, я маплю домен на вьюмодель и обратно маппером, но при этом не использую бд во время маппинга - как то оно у меня так получилось, что мне этого не нужно. Атрибутов я не делал никаких, если мне клиент присылает несуществующий айдишник, то получает 404 в ответ. Поглядите REST и HTTP коды, я по ним ориентировался

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо!  Про автомаппер я все понял. Главное им в базу не лазить, а просто А на В маппить. In memory, так сказать. А вот по поводу "если мне клиент присылает несуществующий айдишник, то получает 404 в ответ." - так надо в базу сходить и проверить, действительно ли такой entity нет. То есть что `_dbContext.YourEntities.Find(id)` даст null я это делаю в фильтрах. Через репозиторий конечно, а не как я тут написал для примера, через контекст. Мне показалось, что этому не место в контроллерах. А вы где такое проверяете?

Comment: Я специально не проверяю наличие энтити аттрибутами. Если юзер запросил запись из бд, то я, прямо в контроллере, 1) найду эту запись в бд (через свою прослойку-репозиторий). Если ее нет в базе, то сразу верну 404 2) сделаю маппинг сущность из бд => вьюмодель 3) верну вьюмодель

Comment: @tym32167 судя по вашим ответам и репутации, вы работаете не первый год с .NET и  MVC . Огромное спасибо за помощь! Мне это было очень полезно!

Comment: Я последние 4 года работаю в десктоп-разработке, потому мои ответы вам - это из остатков того, что я помню + работа над моим домашним проектом. Потому не верьте мне на слово, думайте критически. Чтобы полостью контролировать ваш проект вам надо знать обо всех принятых вами технических решениях, в том числе почему именно они были приняты, какие у них плюсы и минусы в ближней и дальносрочной перспективе.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо еще раз!